# Re-installing Windows 7 on a dual boot system with Fedora

Tags: fedora, windows, system-installation, dual-boot

At present I have a dual boot system with Windows 7 and Fedora 14. I want to re-install windows 7 but most probably it will replace Fedora's boot loader. I have a lot of things set up on Fedora. I want to keep these things intact.

In other words, I want to make an image of my present Fedora system, re-install Windows 7 and have my Fedora system retain the exact state it had before re-installation of Windows 7. Can any one discuss the procedure to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply reinstall Windows 7 and recover the GRUB. Technique for recovering of GRUB bootloader is Luckily covered in [Fedora Manual](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Installation_Guide/ap-rescuemode.html#s2-rescuemode-boot-reinstall-bootloader):

> In many cases, the GRUB boot loader can mistakenly be deleted,
>   corrupted, or replaced by other operating systems.
>
> The following steps detail the process on how GRUB is reinstalled on
>   the master boot record:
>
> - Boot the system from an installation boot medium.
> - Type `linux rescue` at the installation boot prompt to enter the rescue environment.
> - Type `chroot /mnt/sysimage` to mount the root partition.
> - Type `/sbin/grub-install *bootpart*` to reinstall the GRUB boot loader, where `*bootpart*` is the boot partition (typically, `/dev/sda`).
> - Review the `/boot/grub/grub.conf` file, as additional entries may be needed for GRUB to control additional operating systems.
> - Reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

the very simple step for showing fedora after installing windows is that

**1** ) simply insert the dvd of fedora (that's installed in your pc )

**2** ) then enter the installation button and then enter the upgrade or update ....

**3** ) it will automatically detect the installed fedora and then you can reinstall the grub ...

[click here to watch the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbxY1WmacG0)